# how to make TNImageSliderViewController to slide automatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm using [TNImageSliderViewController](https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNImageSliderViewController) and It's working great. The only problem I have with it doesn't have the ability to auto slides image .For example I need the slides to changes every 2 seconds . But How can I add this ability to it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added "Auto slider" and "Reset from beginning" options to [`TNImageSliderViewController`](https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNImageSliderViewController) - and [Frederik](https://github.com/frederik-jacques) has merged the changes. So, now you can update using [pods](https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNImageSliderViewController#installation).

Comment: Thank you very much . Should I download the github zip file again to use the changed you have made ?

Comment: You can either download my copy and update your local files, or wait until [Frederik](https://github.com/frederik-jacques) approves the PR (and then download from his repo - it's up to you).

Comment: I'm new to github . How can I download yours?

Comment: Is it possible to use classes instead of pods ?Because If I run the pod install again it would replace your files with the old ones.

Comment: I think you can just update the content of `Pod/Classes/TNImageSliderViewController.swift` with [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qalandarov/TNImageSliderViewController/master/Pod/Classes/TNImageSliderViewController.swift)